# Typescript: Getting started problems (Cannot find module fs and cannot find name typings)

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am getting to grips with Typescript. I am having issues with using fs.

The following code produces this error: `Ingest.ts(4,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'`.

```
// <reference path="typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
'use strict';

import * as fs from "fs";

console.log("hi matt");
var data = fs.readFileSync('matt.txt');
console.log(data);
```

When I change the first line to /// rather than //

I get this error:

```
typings/node/node.d.ts(512,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IterableIterator'.
typings/node/node.d.ts(514,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IterableIterator'.
typings/node/node.d.ts(515,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IterableIterator'.
```

Prior to trying these I had done these steps:

```
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g tsd@next
cd <project folder>
tsd install node
tsc -init
tsc Ingest.ts
```

Node v.6.4.0 and tsc v.1.8.10 on OSX Yosemite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, a few things here.  `TSD` is done, use `typings` instead `npm install -g typings`.   With `typings`, you need to know the repository for the type files, it will be one of the columns returned when you do a `typings search <package>`.  I've had most of my type files come from the DefinitelyTyped repo.  To install a package from there, you do `typings install dt~<package>`.

Second, you error with the `IterableIterator`, I've already reported this to the Node type team, they are working on a resolution for it, but you can get around it in the mean time by installing the core-js types `typings install dt~core-js --global`

Comment: The DefinitelyTyped GitHub issue for the problem is here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/10919

Comment: My bad, I should have included that since I opened it LOL